# Form of iterate matrix of the QR algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

Given a Matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. I want to consider different (for now isolated) cases of eigenvalues/eigenvectors and would like to know what the QR-algorithm produces. Denote $E_{\lambda_i}$ the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_i$, $\alpha$ its algebraic multilicity and $\gamma:=\dim E_{\lambda_i}$ its geometric multiplicity.

**Case 1**: The matrix has dominant eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and $\gamma = \alpha$. This means the eigenvalue is non-degenerate.

**Case 2**: The matrix has dominant eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and $\gamma < \alpha$. This means the eigenvalue is degenerate.

**Case 3**: The matrix has dominant eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and there exists another eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ for which $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$ but $|\lambda_1|= |\lambda_2|$  and $\gamma = \alpha$ for both eigenvalues.

How does the block Schur-form produced by the QR algorithm in this case look?

Comment: What do expect to happen? You are computing a decomposition $A=QRQ^*$ where $R$ is upper triangular and has the eigenvalues on the diagonal and $Q$ is unitary.

Comment: @LutzLehmann It is not that trivial, but if we dispense of the requirement that the basistransformation is unitary, we can always compute a Jordan form. Even better, if we want to make the basis transformation unitary we can exchange this for only a block schur form. What I intuitively would expect is that whenever we have $|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2|$ we will receive a block, not a strictly diagonal. I guess, that we only get a triangular form if we have eigenvalues which are simple, meaning having algebraic multiplicity one. It is quite hard to tell something more detailed.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit off. By Schur's lemma, every complex lemma is unitarily similar to an upper triangular matrix. A real matrix is not necessarily orthogonally similar to a upper triangular matrix. The best you can hope for is the real Schur form which in general is a upper quasi-triangular matrix with 1-by-1 and 2-by-2 blocks on the main diagonal. Each 1-by-1 block is a real eigenvalue and each 2-by-2 block represents a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues. Regardless, I am still very interested in the answer to your question.

Comment: @CarlChristian What you described is exactly the Block-Schur-Form I was writing about. I have not even mentioned the simple Schur-Form.

Comment: Your matrices are complex, see the very first statement in your question. The QR algorithm will produce an upper triangular matrix in this case.

Comment: @CarlChristian No, only if the ransformation matrices are unitary. But the QR decomposition is always real. The QR algorithm cannot without further modification, produce a complex Schur form.

Comment: No. The Gram-Schmidt algorithm applies to all inner product spaces, real and complex. The QR decomposition exists for real and complex matrices. The QR algorithm with aggressive early deflation is implemented in LAPACK for both real and complex flavors. The only thing I am suggesting is that you specify that you are only interested in real matrices and orthogonal similarity transformations.